# Cross-validation R packages for survival analysis?

Tags: r, cross-validation, weibull

Are there any cross-validation packages in R that work with survival models, like a weibull model?

Comment: I looked for an off-site resource but I couldn't find one. Do I really need to say that in my question?

Comment: It certainly have helped to demonstrate some searching effort. What would have even been more convincing that you had read and understood the rules of SO would have been to construct a simulation and post the code for estimation of a single model and then request enhancements from perhaps the boot library or others.

Answer (score 2):

The `CoxBoost` package has the function `cv.CoxBoost` for cross-validation of survival and competing risks models.

`cvTools` is a package focused on cross-validation. I'm not sure if it has specific functions for survival models, but the package is intended for general cross-validation of regression models.

Answer (score 1):

There are calibration and validation tools in the rms/Hmisc packages that work with survival models. Harrell's RMS text is an extremely useful reference. He demonstrates using parametric (e.g. Weibull) models as well as the semi-parametric Cox models.